# Как правильно получить строку с переносами через input()

Tags: python, список

У меня есть
`n = input()`, пользователь вводит текст через CTRL+V с переносами и нажимает на ENTER:

```
34
45
6
10
```

Но в `n` попадает только 34, из-за переносов. Мне нужно получить список из этого всего. `n = list(map(int,  n.split('\n'))) #[34, 45, 6, 10]`, но по факту получается `['34']`

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Похоже, при вставке в `input` получаются просто пробелы вместо переводов строки, так что используйте просто `input().split()` с параметрами по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, в чем проблема, но вот рабочий вариант. Вставлял через CTRL+V.
На вход:

```
34
45
6
10
```

Сам код

```
a = input('enter')
b=list(a.split(" "))
print(b)
```

На выход:

```
['34', '45', '6', '10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Из стандартного ввода не получить "конец данных" (аналога EOF для файла), но можно считывать до появления пустой строки

```
lines = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break
text = '\n'.join(lines)
print('\n------\n')
print(lines)
```